# Criar formulário em PHP usando resultado recuperado de um query SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Preciso enviar o que foi digitado no campo input e enviar pelo método POST. Meu código está assim:

```
<?php
include_once("../controle/conexao.php");
//Recuperar o valor da palavra
$usuarios = $_POST['palavra'];
echo '$usuarios';

//Pesquisar no banco de dados o nome do usuario referente a palavra digitada
$result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM cadastro_produtos WHERE descricao LIKE '%$usuarios%' OR id LIKE '%$usuarios%' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);

if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_usuarios) <= 0 ){
    echo "Nenhum usuario encontrado";
}else{ 
    while($rows_usuarios = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuarios)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>".$rows_usuarios['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>".$rows_usuarios['descricao']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'><input name='qtd'></td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'> 
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>
                    Adicionar                   

            </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}
?>
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você está falando o input que está dentro do while, para adicionar a quantidade?

Comment: desculpe, <input name='qtd'>

Answer (score 0):

Então para cada linha (tr) você terá que colocar um form.

por exemplo:

```
echo "<tr>";
   echo '<form action="#" method="post">';
     echo "<td class='text-center'>".$rows_usuarios['id']."</td>";
     echo "<td class='text-center'>".$rows_usuarios['descricao']."</td>";
     echo "<td class='text-center'><input name='qtd'></td>";
     echo "<td class='text-center'> 
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>
                    Adicionar</button></td>";
     //no php você vai precisar identificar de quem é a quantidade informada
     //para isso você poderá usar um input hidden
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" value="'.$rows_usuarios['id'].'">';
  echo '</form>';
echo "</tr>";
```

Isso irá funcionar.
Mas lembrando que dessa forma. De colocar o form depois do tr estará quebrando semanticamente o html.
Para isso de uma olhada nesse post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035966/create-a-html-table-where-each-tr-is-a-form

Comment: Obrigado, vou verificar aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer de uma forma mais simples, usando o id de cada produto num array de quantidades:

```
echo '<form action="#" method="post">';
    while( $rows_usuarios = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $resultado_usuarios ) )
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>".$rows_usuarios['id']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>".$rows_usuarios['descricao']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'>";
        echo "<input name='qtd['".$rows_usuarios['id']."']' >";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td class='text-center'> 
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'>
                    Adicionar                   

            </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
echo '</form>';
```

Depois para apanhar os valores é só fazer:

```
$arrayQTD = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qtd', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

foreach( $arrayQTD as $id => $valorDoInputDesseID ) 
{
    //fazer qualquer coisa
]
```

Comment: Obrigado vou estar verificando obrigado

Comment: A primeira parte do código me retornou como <form action="#" method="post"></form>. Está correto isso? fechou form logo em sequência.